# Can I run a .java class in a specific java program with its variables?

Tags: java, minecraft

So again this is one of my Java minecraft plugins, and I'm trying to make a command that runs a specific code that will run on the server, so what I stumbled on is

```
                    String code = "package code; \n"
                            + "public class MyClass { \n"
                            + "    public void myMethod(){ \n"
                            + "        " + args[1] + "\n"
                            + "    } \n"
                            + "}";
                    Dir.save(code, new File(getDataFolder(), "MyClass.java"));
```

so this is my code it will try to save the string in a file, btw please tell me if this string will work as it is meant to be.
then what I want to do In here is that I want to compile this file and run it in my server, its like an external file out side the program, so how do I do it.
How do I run this MyClass.java with the libraries of the server's codes, because I want the code to run with what the server offers from classes!

Answer (score 0):

> this is my code it will try to save the string in a file, btw please tell me if this string will work as it is meant to be

[This part of the question could have been ommitted.](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) You may try to run that code snippet and check if the file will be saved as you want it to; if it is, then the answer is yes. Otherwise, it is no.

---

It is possible to dinamically compile and execute code in the server. To achieve this effect, you may want to take a look at:

- [Dynamic code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166135/dynamic-code-execution/4166235#4166235)
- [Set up Java compiler on server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241309/set-up-java-compiler-on-server)
- Java's [JavaCompiler interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Comment: You still don't get it I want to run the MyClass.java as in external file, I mean like if it was in C:\Program Files\MyClass.java or tell me if I can load the MyClass.java file as an object then compile and run with the server's libraries

Comment: @hamoodrex If you want people to understand what you're asking, word your question better.