# how to compile java code setting classloader (via ant task)

Tags: java, ant, compilation, classloader, javac

I need to set the classloader of javac of my task ant which compiles my code.. 
i ve read [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945971/use-a-custom-classloader-at-compile-time) but this

`javac -J-Djava.system.class.loader=org.awesome.classloader sourcefile.java`

didnt worked for me, always returning class not found exception.. and, yes, i set the classpath for the source code and the compiled classloader **.class**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some study of this task I found a way. I initialized a custom classloader and then I used it through the new Compiler API from Java 6

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html